# SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow Copy List Item Creates Duplicate Entries

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a very simple workflow set on a list that does the following:

A) If ColumnName:Random equals Approved, Copy item in Current Item to CopiedList

That's it.

If a choice column named 'Random' has a value of 'Approved', copy the list item to another list.

Only problem is the copy randomly copies duplicate copies. I have the workflow settings> start options set to 'Start workflow automatically when an item is changed'.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I think you need to give more information on how the workflow looks like. Anyway, you can put Log actions before/after each suspect workflow action, that will give you some idea on how many times an action executes.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by duplicate copies? Is it that it copies multiple copies of the same item or does it take a copy of a different item? And how does the column 'Random' gets the value 'Approved'. Is it from another workflow. Or is it an update done directly to the list item?

Comment: The list has only one column (besides Title) and it's called 'Random'. It's a choice column, and the only two values are 'Approved' and 'Rejected'. It's not pulling any values from anywhere else. So if I have an item created and then go back and change the value to 'Approved', it should copy it to another list, but it copies the list item twice.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this a lot and this seems to be an issue with workflows that are set to autostart. I discovered that if I set the workflow to pause for 1 minute as the first step, it doesn't create multiple copies